# CSS menu underline slide without javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I created a pen that has a nice slide effect between elements in menu.

```
<ul>
  <li id="home"><a>home</a></li>
  <li id="libra"><a>libra</a></li>
   <li id="libra2"><a>libra22</a></li>
  <div class="line"></div>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li a {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.line {
 width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#libra:hover ~ div {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPxmZV

However, that only works forwards, not backwards and it's not dynamic, you pre-set the margin amount of the underline to slide with transition.

Is there a way to make it work forwards and backwards, and be dynamic without javascript?

and if not, what would be the best clean way with javascript?

**Explained**
For example, currently it's hardcoded, so if you hover `#libra` your underline will go right by 100px, so currently I need to add that case for every element in the array, for example the next element will be margin left 200px, etc.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want the underline to stay under the hover element?

Comment: No, I want to make it calculate where to slide to dynamically based on where you hover, without hard codding it via CSS by element id

Comment: But you already have the solution, either way, you'll have to target each list element so you can move the underline to its position. Same on JS. There are many ways to accomplish the same thing you did in CSS, but I assure you that they are not simpler than yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have created it using Translate property:

**Without hardcoding you'll have to use javascript with alot of calculations**

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:black;
}

nav ul,
nav li,
nav a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  outline: none;
  color: ghostwhite;
}

nav ul:hover,
nav li:hover,
nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line,
nav li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line,
nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110px);
          transform: translate(110px);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul:nth-child(3):hover ~ .line,
nav li:nth-child(3):hover ~ .line,
nav a:nth-child(3):hover ~ .line {
  -webkit-transform: translate(240px);
          transform: translate(240px);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul:nth-child(4):hover ~ .line,
nav li:nth-child(4):hover ~ .line,
nav a:nth-child(4):hover ~ .line {
  -webkit-transform: translate(340px);
          transform: translate(340px);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul:nth-child(5):hover ~ .line,
nav li:nth-child(5):hover ~ .line,
nav a:nth-child(5):hover ~ .line {
  -webkit-transform: translate(450px);
          transform: translate(450px);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line,
nav li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line,
nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .line {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110px);
          transform: translate(110px);
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

nav .line {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#product-test">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#quote">Quota</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```